# window 10 to 11 update stuck at 88% while booting. giving invalid data_access_trap

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-11

I need some help. I have been trying to upgrade to windows 11 from windows 10. It downloads and installs and everything is fine until it goes into booting. It installs and then when it reaches 88% (while booting) it says "some error occurred and undoing all the changes made".. something. I have tried a lot of things from youtube and have tried installing like 9-10 times, but the same thing happens. I am okay with windows 10 for now but just curious that if someday I may have to upgrade I may get stuck.
I did a lot of things already, removed media players, my drivers are already updated, and even tried windows 11 installer assistant.[problem-description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNzic.jpg)[problem description2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9i2N.jpg)

Comment: Did you remove *all* media-connected apps? Other reported problematic apps are SVLoadSense, Realtek audio driver, FiiO USB Audio Driver, mySQL Workbench, MySQLServer, AverMedia.

Comment: i deleted almost everything photoshop, premiere pro, xampp. now it installed

Comment: I added an answer for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 11 upgrade is very particular about the installed products that
it accepts, so will fail if when scanning the disk it finds products
that it doesn't like.

Some such products are media-connected apps, SVLoadSense,
Realtek audio driver, FiiO USB Audio Driver, mySQL Workbench,
MySQLServer, AverMedia.

The poster also added Photoshop, Premiere Pro and xampp.

The upgrade also doesn't like some versions of cracked software.

Some of these products can be installed back *after* the upgrade is done.

Answer (score 0):

Go to GitHub and get, download and run WhyNotWin11.exe and see what the issue is.

[WhyNotWin11](https://github.com/rcmaehl/WhyNotWin11/releases)

**(A)** You need UEFI BIOS (not legacy), TPM V2, Secure Boot functional, disk formatted as GPT, and CPU Generation 3 years or newer.

These are the main points, but run the tool

[image]

.
.

**(B)** If the results are all good (all green) meaning your computer will run Windows 11 (I have one computer like that and the upgrade went well), then try the following:

1. Remove older or unnecessary software at least temporarily.
2. Update mainstream software (Office, Adobe and like software) to the newest versions.
3. Be sure to update all drivers (manufacturer's Driver Update App)
4. Then run a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation Link (second link on that page) and use the option (default) to Keep Everything.
5. Final restart and try upgrading to Windows 11 again.

Comment: i tried the whynotwin11.exe file. It shows all green. my bios is UEFL.TPM2,disk is set to GPT. One additional thing i want to add is that maybe once i was trying to install some software and it was corrupt and my pc went on to restart again and again until i reset my pc. None of my data was lot. is possible that it has something to do with it?

Comment: I amended my post to remove (temporarily) non-mainstream software and run a Window 10 Repair Install and then try upgrading again.

Comment: update  - i got it this time right, i deleted all crack software I had and it installed. thanks for support

Answer (score 0):

Some corrupt component make a upgrade to win 11 fail, well there is no other way you need a clean install it, with some backup first of course

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1176905)